# org.w3c.dom.DOMException has no detalied message when replaceChild()

Tags: java, dom

I'm trying to replace a node of a document for other node with the same structure from another document (the rest of structure and origin of the two documents is different) using this method:

```
 public static void replaceLines(Document target, Document source){
        Node sourceNode =source.getElementsByTagName("lines").item(0);
        Node targetNode=target.getElementsByTagName("lines").item(0);
        target.getChildNodes().item(0).replaceChild(sourceNode,targetNode);
    }
```

Notice that:

```
target.getElementsByTagName("lines").item(0) = target.getChildNodes().item(0)
```

And I get this exception:

```
10-20 16:19:48.259 20021-20021/myapp.mygestion E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: myapp.mygestion, PID: 20021
org.w3c.dom.DOMException
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.InnerNodeImpl.insertChildAt(InnerNodeImpl.java:118)
    at org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.InnerNodeImpl.replaceChild(InnerNodeImpl.java:199)
    at mygestion.com.utiles.XmlEditor.replaceLines(XmlEditor.java:128)
    at mygestion.com.DetalleFicha$9.onPostExecute(DetalleFicha.java:1078)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

As I said it has no detailed message and I cant find the cause of the error, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Exception is being thrown as you try to replace a node from a source document to a target document. As specified in the `replaceChild(Node newChild, Node oldChild)` [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#replaceChild(org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.Node)), a DOMException is being thrown if the new child is created from another document.
You should try to clone the node, create it with the target document and then append/replace it.